# AppleScript: Download URL from file and keep the names

Tags: applescript

I want to create a simple AppleScript:

- define a folder (that will get all the images, docs etc.)
- read a file (.txt for example)
- download all the URLs into the folder with their original name

Currently, my file has one URL by line, no separator.

I found several scripts but they always do something I don't want, don't need or doesn't work.

I found one that is very close to what I want, but it's editing the names in the loop.
I didn't succeed to split the URL and keep the last part.
Here it is:

```
property desktopPath : path to desktop as string

set n to 1
repeat with urlLine in paragraphs of (read alias (desktopPath & "filename.txt"))
    set qURL to quoted form of urlLine
    if qURL ≠ "''" then
        set dest to quoted form of ¬
            (POSIX path of desktopPath & "URLs/" & n & ".jpg")
        do shell script "curl " & quoted form of urlLine & " > " & dest
        set n to n + 1
    end if
end repeat
```

If you have any other solution, I take.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When the primary _utility_ is a _command line utility_ I see little reason to wrap it in **AppleScript**. I'd just do it directly in **Terminal** with a _compound command_ such as, e.g.: `while IFS= read -r line; do cd '/path/to/save_to' || exit; [ -w "$(pwd)" ] || exit; curl -O "${line}"; done < '/path/to/URLs.txt'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The idea of the Apple Script here is that I can also share it easily with people that are not "code friendly". Even though it's code inside, I can share a file they can save and use it when they want. I add a bit of comments for the folder and file, and they can do it by themselves :)
For your suggestion, I got a problem when I'm doing it. My terminal tab is closing right after I executed it (and images are not downloaded).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a script that is working fine.

You just need to be sure about the txt file: the list inside should not have any text format.
Weirdly I have to do a copy/paste through a text editor to remove every text format.

1/ Put the txt file on your desktop, 2/ Create a "download" folder on your desktop, 3/ Start the script

```
set theList to (path to desktop as text) & "Download.txt" -- File name with the URLs
set theFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "download" -- Folder name between quotes
set theFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of theFolder 
set theImages to read alias theList as list using delimiter linefeed

repeat with i from 1 to count of theImages
set thisItem to item i of theImages
do shell script "cd " & theFolder & "; " & "curl -O " & quoted form of thisItem
end repeat
```